# Android Permission When Installing App from Computer

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I just installed my app in progress on a Nexus 9 tablet with Android 6.0.1 on it. When I launched my app, I noticed that things were messed up. In fact, the permissions were not granted even if declared in my Manifest. When I installed it on my phone running Android 5.1, I didn't have to do anything and the permissions were granted.

Is there something I'm missing about permissions or certain devices won't allow permission unless you have a confirmation from the Play Store and a user prompt?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html `Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that things were messed up. In fact, the permissions were not granted even if declared in my Manifest.

You most likely build your app against Marshmallow SDK (API23) w/o supporting new permission model ([docs](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)) in code. This is not going to work. As quick solution change `target-sdk` to `22` (or lower) and build your app again. Or add support for runtime permissions.